# How do I return a color to its import color after renderer.material.color?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I imported a custom sprite from Photoshop, and its color was purple. I want it so that when the button is pressed, it changes color. When I used `renderer.material.color = Color.cyan;`, and once the button is pressed, I have no idea how to make the color of the button return back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do that. You can, however, store the original color before modifying it and the reassign it back:

```
Color originalColor;

void Awake()
{
    originalColor = renderer.sharedMaterial.color;  
}
void ChangeColor(Color newColor)
{
    renderer.material.color = newColor;
}
void ResetDefaultColor()
{
    renderer.material.color = originalColor;
}
```

Comment: @Abaseen Khan: that's c#..at least try to translate it by your own. it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that my answer, at its core, is the same as Heisenbug's, but in UnityScript.

```
private var original : Color;

function Start () 
{
    original = renderer.sharedMaterial.color;  
}

function changeColor(newColor : Color)
{
    renderer.material.color = newColor;
}

function resetColor()
{
    changeColor(original);
}
```

This is how you use it:

```
changeColor(Color.black);
```